# getting environment variables from windows

Tags: ruby, windows, environment-variables

According to some answers the following should give me the environment variable username in windows.
But is just gives SYSTEM. I know of other methods to get the username but what is the easiest way to get an invironment variable in Ruby193/Windows7 ?

```
puts ENV['USERNAME'] #=> SYSTEM
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found it ! Allthough i didn't get an error but a wrong result (my username is certainly not SYSTEM and i run the script in the interpreter, nothing fancy) i had to require win32ole.
I noticed this earlier, windows script don't run or give not the expected result but don't complain about mising something and when you include some library it suddenly works.

```
require 'win32ole'
puts ENV['username'] #=> peter
```

EDIT: and when i try it now it suddenly works without the require, spooky ! I'll do some testing on other W7 pc's and keep you posted.

Answer (score 0):

That *is* the way of getting the contents of an environment variable. Regardless of the OS.

If that returns `SYSTEM` then your username *is* `SYSTEM`.

Answer (score 0):

If your process is running as a service (as a web server would, for instance) then `SYSTEM` is the correct answer.  You can change the service to run as a different user (but I suspect that's not what you want to do).